# Error: Cannot resolve symbol mGoogleApiClient

Tags: google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-api-client

So I'm trying to connect google drive to android studio. I have the following code in MainActivity.java file and it gives me an error. Any help is appreciated.

```
package com.example.malik.shoutout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you updated/added the Google Play Services dependency in your `build.gradle` file and clean/rebuild your project?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't declare a variable mGoogleApiClient

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem adding:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient
```

This is my complete code:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, (GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

Comment: what is the value of Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API and gso?